# bash: how to put variable into loop-command not found

Tags: bash, json

```
jq '.issues[].fields.subtasks[].fields | .issuetype.subtask' 1.json
```

works as expected (getting "true" as  output)
when trying to put command above as variable

```
for custom_field in `cat 1.json | jq .issues[].fields.subtasks[].fields | .issuetype.subtask`; do
      echo $customfield
done
```

getting:.

```
issuetype.subtask: command not found
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
for custom_field in $(
    jq '.issues[].fields.subtasks[].fields | .issuetype.subtask' 1.json
); do
      echo "$customfield"
done
```

Or better with a *while loop* if you have values with spaces :

```
while IFS= read -r customfield; do
    echo "$customfield"
done < <(jq '.issues[].fields.subtasks[].fields | .issuetype.subtask' 1.json)
```

### Note :

- you need to '*quote*' the [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) expression
- jq can read file by itself, no need `cat`
- stop using backticks ` in 2018 please use **$( )**
- `< <( )` is a bash-only feature, not available in other shells (or even in bash when it's invoked as sh). So start your script with a bash shebang `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash` and don't override that by running the script with the `sh` command

Comment: Note that `<( )` is a bash-only feature, not available in other shells (or even in bash when it's invoked as `sh`). So start your script with a bash shebang (`#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`) and don't override that by running the script with the `sh` command.